# Extracting text from XML Element with attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file like this one:

```
<root>
<image size = "small">www.linktosmallimage.jpg</image>
<image size = "large">www.linktolargeimage.jpg</image>
</root>
```

Im extracting the first link in this way:

```
foreach (XmlElement x in xmlSource.SelectNodes("/root"))
            {
             string s = x.SelectSingleNode("image").InnerText;
            }
```

The question is: How do I get the second link? (the link for the large image, since is the only one that I need)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't trust the order and you want to use the size attribute do:

```
x.SelectSingleNode("image[@size='large']")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
foreach(XmlElement x in xmlSource.SelectNodes("/root/image"))
{
  s = x.InnerText;
}
```

if you always want the last one.
Or you can do:

```
        XmlNode y = xmlSource.SelectSingleNode("/root/image[@size=\"large\"]");
        string s = y.InnerText;
```

in which case the order of the elements doesn't matter, you will always get the element with the attribute size = large assuming there is only one such element.  If the assumption holds this is the better approach.  Here are some good [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`x.SelectSingleNode("image[2]")`

Strangely, XPath arrays begin on [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) rather than [0].

Lots of information on XPath here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

By the way, you should look into [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) -- the syntax is bulkier, but it's a bit more robust.